# Node.js: how to use proxyquire for replacing neo4j-driver dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon

I must have some fundamental problem understanding of how proxyquire works or doing something wrong.

For a proof of concept I have this original code connecting to neo4j graphnedb in node.js:

```
// I am lib/neo4j.js    
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

var graphenedbURL = process.env.GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_URL;
var graphenedbUser = process.env.GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_USER;
var graphenedbPass = process.env.GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_PASSWORD;

var driver = neo4j.driver(graphenedbURL, neo4j.auth.basic(graphenedbUser, graphenedbPass));
```

Then I have this test:

```
// I am test/neo4j.test.js
'use strict';
const test = require('tap').test;
const proxy = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

test('Testing connection to Neo4j', (assert) => {
    const driverStub = sinon.stub();
    const testedModule = proxy('../lib/neo4j', {
         'neo4j': {
            'driver': driverStub,
          },
      });
});
```

Test is run as npm tap test/*.test.js --conv

Because npm does not provide access to .env for heroku graphnedb the driver won't have any process.env connection variables which should be ok since my expectation is that proxyquire will replace the driver with above defined stub but that's not happening and the test fails on neo4j.driver missing graphnedebURL. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: const testedModule = proxy('../lib/neo4j', {
         'neo4j-driver': {
            'v1': {
                driver: driverStub
            },
          },
      });

Try this.

Comment: yep, thats it... I spent something around 6 hours on this... I knew someone's gonna make me feel retarded :D anyway, thank you for the help. If you make it a standalone answer I will be happy to approve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to proxyquire neo4j the same way you are requiring in the original file, including v1.

```
 // I am test/neo4j.test.js
 'use strict';
 const test = require('tap').test;
 const proxy = require('proxyquire');
 const sinon = require('sinon');

 test('Testing connection to Neo4j', (assert) => {
    const driverStub = sinon.stub();
    const testedModule = proxy('../lib/neo4j', 
    { 
        'neo4j-driver': { 
            'v1': {
                driver: driverStub 
            },
        }, 
    });
 });
```